# ReactJs always print the same id

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to create a table with some data in it and I have problem on printing the right id.

First I created the parent component with the table and all the relative elements.

Inside the `<tbody>` I'm running a `map()` function where it loops through the whole `array` and return for each `object` a `<TaskRow />` component.

**Array of objects**

```
let maintenance_task = [
    {
        task_id: 1,
        task: 'task 1',
        description: '',
        date: '2020-02-02'
    },
    {
        task_id: 2,
        task: 'task 2',
        description: '',
        date: '2020-02-02'
    },
    {
        task_id: 3,
        task: 'task 3',
        description: '',
        date: '2020-02-02'
    },
    {
        task_id: 4,
        task: 'task 4',
        description: '',
        date: '2020-02-02'
    }
]
```

**Parent component**

```
<tbody id="list-tasks">
   {
      props.maintenance_task.map( (task, index) => {
         return (
            <TaskRow
               key={ index }
               task={ task } 
            />
         );
      })
   }
</tbody>
```

**Child component.**

```
import React from 'react';

function TaskRow(props) {

    const toggle_delete_task = (task_id) => {

        console.log(task_id);

        const confirm_remove_task = document.getElementById('remove-task');
        const loading_animation = document.getElementById('loading-animation-section');

        confirm_remove_task.classList.toggle('d-block');
        loading_animation.classList.toggle('d-block');
    }

    return (
        <tr>
            <td><p>{ props.task.task }</p></td>
            <td><p>{ props.task.description }</p></td>
            <td><p>{ props.task.date }</p></td>

            <td className="wrap-inputs-task">
                <input type="button" value="Edit" />
                <input type="button" value="Delete" onClick={ () => toggle_delete_task(props.task.task_id) } /> // delete button
            </td>

            <td id="remove-task" className="confirm-remove-task">
                <p>Are you sure you want to remove this task ?</p>

                <span>
                    <input type="button" value="Confirm" />
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onClick={ () => toggle_delete_task(props.task.task_id) } /> // cancel button
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
}

export default TaskRow;
```

When I click delete button it runs `toggle_delete_task()` where it will print in the console the current `task_id` and show `remove-task` element.

The problem is after, when I click cancel button and run the same function `toggle_delete_task()` it will always print `1` in the console, which is the first `task_id` of the `objects` inside the `array`.

Comment: What is `get_maintenance_task` and your child is expecting `props.task` but can't see in your parent component?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma ``get_maintenance_task`` it's function that I'm passing's and it supposed to do something else. Sorry I forgot to insert ``task`` when I was writing the code here, I edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your `remove-task` element has the same `id`, that when you do `document.getElementById('remove-task')` it only select's the firs `remove-task` element which belongs to `task 1`.

You have to give each of them a different `id`s, probably appending the current `task`'s `task_id`.

```js
<td
  id={`remove-task-${props.task.task_id}`} // notice this
  className="confirm-remove-task"
>
...
```

Then on your `toggle_delete_task`, make sure to get the correct `confirm_remove_task` element.

```js
const toggle_delete_task = (task_id) => {
  console.log(task_id);
  
  const confirm_remove_task = document.getElementById(
    `remove-task-${props.task.task_id}`
  );
  
  ...
  };
```

---

Or a cleaner approach is to create a variable for the `remove-task` element's id, and reference that when assigning and selecting the element by id.

```js
function TaskRow(props) {
  const removeTaskElementId = `remove-task-${props.task.task_id}`;
...
```